# Why does the JPanel not display on the Frame?

Tags: java, swing

i got the following Code, which is a shortened Version of the actual problem i have:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Circle {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Painter panel = new Painter();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }






    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;


    public class Painter extends JPanel{

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5663520834139683160L;
        /**
         * @param args
         */



        Painter()
        {
        }

        public void drawPlayer(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, 200, 30);
            //g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            //g.drawRect(0, 0, 80, 50);
            //g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            //g.fillRect(0, 0, 80/2, 50/2);
            //g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            //g.drawString("BOB", 10/2+10, 5/2);
        }

        @Override

        public void printComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            this.drawPlayer(g);
        }
    }
```

When I execute it, the JPanel doesnt show up and I just can't find the mistake.

Don't know if this is important, but in the actual problem I initialize the JFrame with its JPanels in the constructor but it doesnt work either.

If necessary I can post the original code. The actual task is to provide a GUI for a ConnectFour game where the Frame is divided up into a JPanel drawing the discs and another JPanel providing player information like name etc. . The first part is working fine but the last part just won't work. (Don't get confuse by this code i posted drawing a circle. I wanted to post the structure of the solution i'm considering for the players information Panel.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the JPanel not display on the Frame?

It should be overridden `paintComponent()` method instead of `printComponent()` method

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     this.drawPlayer(g);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is totally embarrassing. I just didn't notice this.

Thanks a lot !!!